# Go to a specific line in file and read it

Tags: c++, file, fread, seekg

## Problem description

I have a file containing a set of lines. A

**File 1:**

```
"Hello How are you"

"The cat ate the mouse"
```

---

Based on the the beginning and ending of the lines given by the user as input. I want to go to each line in the file and Extract it.

For examples if user types **1** , **17** then I have to go to line **1** that has a size of **17** characters. He can give any line number in the file.

I read the following Answer [Read from a specific spot in a file C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968565/read-from-a-specific-spot-in-a-file-c). But I didn't really understand. Why do the lines have to be the same size? If i have the information concerning the beginning and ending of every line in the file. Why can't I access it directly?

---

### Source code

I tried to use the following code which was inspired by [Read Data From Specified Position in File Using Seekg](http://code.runnable.com/UpS-Gao_xYtKAAAe/read-data-from-specified-position-in-file-using-seekg-for-c%2B%2B-and-fstream) But I couldn't extract the lines why?

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std::

    void getline(int, int, const ifstream & );
    int main()
    {
      //open file1 containing the sentences
      ifstream file1("file1.txt");

      int beg = 1;
      int end = 17;
      getline(beg,end, file1);

      beg = 2;
      end = 20;
      getline(beg,end, file1);

      return 0;
    }

void getline(int beg, int end, const ifstream & file)
{
   file.seekg(beg, ios::beg); 
   int length = end;

   char * buffer = new char [length];

   file.read (buffer,length);

   buffer [length - 1] = '\0'; 

   cout.write (buffer,length);
   delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: Remove `using namespace std::` (won't compile BTW, I suspect in your real code you have `using namespace std;`).

Comment: so the first number tells you what line to read in the file and the second tells you how many characters to read from that line? what is the result of your current code? what happens when you run it?

Comment: "If i have the information concerning the beginning and ending of every line in the file" then yes, it would be possible to seek directly to any arbitrary line. But your code doesn't show that you have that information.

Comment: Extra hint: You are not going to be able to read from a const fstream. If your compiler is allowing that and building you an executable, get a new compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code appears to be using line numbers as byte offsets.  If you seek to offset "1" the file seeks forward 1 byte, not 1 line.  If you seek to offset 2, the file seeks forward 2 bytes, not 2 lines.

To seek to a specific line you need to read the file and count the number of line breaks until you get to the line you want.  There is code that already does this, for example `std::getline()`.  If you don't already know the exact *byte* offset of the line you want, you can call `std::getline()` the number of times equal to the line number you want.

Also remember that the first byte of a file is at offset 0 not offset 1, and that different platforms use different bytes to indicate the end of a line (E.g. on Windows it's `"\r\n"`, on Unix it's `"\n"`).  If you're using a library function to read lines, the line ending should be taken care of for you.

Comment: Thank you @Alice Asker. What I did is that instead of using the line numbers I used the Bytes. For every line I count it's length + '\0'. The next line starts at the end of line 1 plus 1. it's working perfectly now. Really good explanation